# lsim command with initial condition

Tags: matlab, simulation, state-space

while using the `lsim` command of matlab I found out that the initial condition in my program doesn't affect the simulation's output.

```
y = lsim(F,input,time,x0);
```

Where `F` is a transfer function, and `x0` the initial condition that I calculate with the state-space model. 
The value of `x0` doesn't affect `y`, I even replaced it with different numbers and the simulation's output `y` is always the same.

I'm actually trying to get the parameters of the tf from a real measured output. So that's the main part of the code:

```
tsmpl = 1e-2;
Sizeof_y = length(y_real);
R        = zeros(Sizeof_y,3);      

R(1,:) = [y_real(1) input(1) 0];

for i=2:Sizeof_y
          R(i,:)=[y_real(i-1) input(i) input(i-1)]; 
end
p   = pinv(R)*y_real;
z   = tf('z',tsmpl);
num = p(2)*z+p(3);
den = z-p(1);
F   = num/den;
sys = ss(F); 

x0  = (y_real(1) - (sys.d*sig(1)))*pinv(sys.c);

y  = lsim(F,input,time,x0);
```

`y_real` is the measured output. It's a vector of complexe numbers. 
`time`   is the time vector that represents the duration of the process. (given by the measurment) `time = 6:0.01:24` 
`input`  represents the test signal which is a vector defined like this:

```
Size_input = length(time);   

Size_sine  = length(halftime) ;   %halftime is the duration of the exitation also known from the measurment
input      = zeros(Size_input,1);

input(1:Size_sine) = complex(30);
```

Vectors `y_real`, `time`, and `input` have the same length.

I would be thankful for any idea :))

Comment: Maybe your system is unaffected by inputs. Care to share the full code?

Comment: `@AnderBiguri`  I added the code in the question. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @BenJo In the code you provided there are many variables that are not initialized such as: `Sizeof_y`, `y_real`, `tsmpl` and `ZD`. Can you provide this piece of code?

Comment: @Cebri ...thx.  Done.  The problem is that some of them are measured values.